# How do I deliver all burgers in under one minute?

Tags: borderlands-3

In the mission **Dynasty Dash: Eden-6** you have to deliver burgers to five locations spread all across the map on a ten minute timer. One of the bonus objectives is to deliver all burgers with 9:00 minutes remaining.

How can this be achieved? Also if it's possible: what is the bonus reward for doing so.

Comment: For missions like this in BL2, me and my friends would clear enemies from the area around the drop points first  then camp on as many as possible before someone triggers the timer. Instant delivery of three drops. For solo - just clear enemies so you get a clean run

Comment: Please take into account that burder missions also offer possibility to increase remaining time by destroying nearby posters.

Comment: The only reward seems to be more cash. There isn't any hidden reward for doing it in under 1 minute. The mission can be repeated an unlimited number of times.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This mission in particular has a secondary objective that is mentioned but not labelled on the quest tracker. Shooting competitors signs will add some seconds to your remaining time. They are highlighted red and are seen as you drive between the different delivery points.

Comment: nice find. And also, Burgerlands 3 *scnr*

Comment: It's actually not delivering it under 1 minute, but finish the delivery with more than 9 minutes to spare.  The difference is you can add time by shooting signs, so strictly speaking, this is not answering the question but is actually the correct answer.